# load html fragment with dynamic content

Tags: jquery, html, jsp, social-networking

First of all In Jquery loading html frag with dynamic content using load() is it a good aproach?

If yes when you load html fragment with load()  from the server under JSP environment,How do you style the page with css?do you insert css syntax in the html frag inside jsp or you wait until you load it to the client side?
To clarify more the html fragment i am trying to load is inbox page with a list of messages from friends just like linked-in or facebook.Any different advice will also be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) For short, simple HTML, I don't think there's anything wrong with using jQuery's load method. For more in depth data loading, I would suggest looking into the jQuery.getJSON() method, and then parsing that jSON object to build your HTML

2) As far as the CSS, there is no need to do any inline CSS. Instead, just give your fragment an ID or a class, and define the attributes for that in an external stylesheet.

Comment: So in my case i shouldnt use getJSON()instead of load() ?